# broadcast receiver doesn't receive intent

Tags: java, android

I have a simple broadcast receiver that should call a method when a phone is turn on after being powered of or rebooted. but it doesn't receive any calls

```
  public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        MainActivity.activateMidnightService(true);
        Log.e("myReceiver", "turned on");
    } 
}
}
```

and I registered it in the manifest

```
    <receiver
        android:name="hasebou.karim.simplify.MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5439320/905349).

Comment: Do you have an `<activity>`, and, if yes, have you run that activity before rebooting? Rajen's answer is at least part of your problem, but you also need to manually run some component of your app, such as launching an activity, before your `BroadcastReceiver` will work.

Comment: i have an activity that runs before rebooting

Comment: Rajen's answer worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove

```
android:permission="android.permission.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

from receiver tag and add below line outside application tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```